# Как добавить данные во все ajax запросы?

Tags: jquery, yii2

Здравствуйте, как можно добавить данные (cscrf token) ко всем ajax запросам?

Comment: добавьте в post данные эту переменную и отправляйте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но если в layout есть `Html::csrfMetaTags()`, то csrf token должен автоматически добавляться во все Ajax-запросы.

В [yii.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.js#L345) есть такая вот функция:

```
function initCsrfHandler() {
    // automatically send CSRF token for all AJAX requests
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, xhr) {
        if (!options.crossDomain && pub.getCsrfParam()) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', pub.getCsrfToken());
        }
    });
    pub.refreshCsrfToken();
}
```

P.S. Если я все-таки ошибаюсь, то Вы можете передавать токен "руками":

```
var csrfParam = $('meta[name="csrf-param"]').attr("content");
var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {param1: param1, csrfParam : csrfToken},
});
```

[Использование csrf-токенов в Yii2](http://onfor.info/yii2-ispolzovanie-csrf-tokenov/)